# Memory space of ARM microprocessors

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture, microprocessors

In ARM microprocessors, is the only available memory space the 37 or so general and status registers, or is there a separate accessible memory space within the microprocessor chip?

For example, in the Atmel AVR microcontroller, to my understanding, the memory is mapped internally within the same chip, with data memory, program memory (containing program memory) and EEPROM memory. Does the same apply to ARM microprocessors, or does a microcontroller with an ARM microprocessor require separate external memory?

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation of the Atmel AVR architecture is not quite correct.

Of course it's possible to integrate memory of virtually any kind on the same die as the CPU core. However, that doesn't mean you can compare flash memory available on one such integrated system to registers on another.

A CPU core needs a memory interface and that's all that counts: Flash is slower than registers. So if you connect Flash to an ARM processor it will behave similar (in the same order of magniture regarding speed) as the on-board Flash of the AVR.

Besides, ARM is solely an IP (design concept) and licenced by numerous companies which build efficient peripherals and sometimes also memory around the core. So you will find chips with an ARM core and on-board memory on the market.

(I simplified things a bit in the above description but I was focusing on trying to point out where I think you misunderstand how the two processors compare.)

Comment: Thanks for writing! I would like to ask though, does the ARM core require a separate memory space to store the program code (i.e. instructions) which it can read/write?

Comment: Again, you're comparing the _ARM core_ with the _AVR chip_, which is a core _plus_ memory. As I said, the ARM core is just a _design_, not a _chip_. You're trying to compare two things which do not belong to the same category. It's abit as if you were asking, "does the BMW 3 litres engine require an external gearshift, because I saw that the Chrysler Voyager already has one?"

Comment: sorry if I misunderstand, but don't ARM core models (e.g. the cortex-A series) specify details on the configuration of the memory space? For example, wouldn't there be specifications on where the program code can be stored?

Comment: (i.e. where would the program memory be stored?)

Comment: Code can be located in RAM or ROM on modern processors, the CPU pretty much doesn't care. Heard of stack overflows? ;) It's the _application_ which decides where code will finally be executed. But I'm not sure that this was your question. Maybe if you give a motivation for your question, I can better understand which information you _really_ need.

Answer (score 0):

Below link talks a lot about how memory management is done in ARM processor. Hope it helps

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0471c/CHDDJIFI.html